# Como fazer o tratamento de erro para Google Play Services desatualizado evitando travamento do aplicativo no android?

Tags: android, google-play

Estou criando um aplicativo que utiliza **Firebase**, e que por sua vez utiliza o **Google Play Services**.

Nos meus testes, quando o *Google Play Services* está desatualizado, ele trava o aplicativo e da um erro dizendo que o aplicativo parou.

Em seguida, aparece uma notificação dizendo: 
**Atualizar o Google Play Services - Aplicativo só funciona com uma versão atualizada do Google Play Services.**

É possível fazer um tratamento de erro para avisar ao usuário que a atualização do Google Play Services é necessária sem travar o aplicativo e fechá-lo?

Ele da erro pra mim quando executo esta linha:

```
 Button loginbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               LoginProcess("emailteste@gmail.com ", "senha123456");
            }
        });
```

...

```
public void LoginProcess(String email, String password){
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Logado com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getParent(), "Falha de Login.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código que usa "para obter" os serviços do Google Play Services.

Comment: Obrigado por responder @ramaral, acabei conseguindo resolver. O código que utilizava o google play services ja estava na pergunta, que é o **FirebaseUser** do firebase que por sua vez precisa do Google Play Services para funcionar.  Ja adicionei a resposta com minha solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

Encontrei um código desatualizado na net, depois de horas pesquisando, e atualizando pro novo método ficou assim dentro de uma função que criei:

```
public Boolean GServicesCheck() {
    int result = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    switch(result) {
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
            Toast.makeText(this, "O Google Play Services precisa ser atualizado para acessar esta função.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("FVRLOG","SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED");
            return false;
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            Log.d("FVRLOG", "Play service available success");
            return true;
        default:
            Log.d("FVRLOG", "unknown services result: " + result);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Houve um erro com o Google Play Services, entre em contato com o administrador.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
    }
}
```

E agora eu faço a checagem toda vez que vou executar algo que utilize o Google Play Services desta forma:

```
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         if(GServicesCheck()) {
           LoginProcess("emailteste@gmail.com ", "senha123456");
         }
        }
```